# How to construct a C++ string from sequence of bytes?

Tags: c++

Given

```
const void * data = ...;
size_t size = ...;

std::string message(???)
```

How to construct `std::string` from raw pointer to data and size of the data? `data` may contain NUL characters.

Comment: If the data could contain zero characters, then it is not a zero-terminated string. In which case it is not clear what you want to get in your `std::string`.

Comment: @DonReba `std::string` is just a string, not a *zero-terminated* string

Comment: The follow-up question is, do you really need an `std::string`, or would `std::vector<char>` be more suitable?

Comment: @juanchopanza what's the benefit of `std::vector<char>` over `std::string` (aside of readability)?

Comment: @vladon It has a simpler interface which is easier to understand. And it makes the intent clear. It represents a char buffer, not a readable string object. It also doesn't need a `\0` tagged on at the end. So it really depends on your use-case.

Comment: ... and if you use `std::string`, then your code (or anyone else's code that uses your code) can't then use `string::c_str()` without potential bugs creeping in - should be obvious but probably worth restating.

Comment: @Component10 I use `string::data()`, but in all modern realizations `string::c_str()` doing the same as `string::data()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[string constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) can work with `char*`, that contains `\0`, if `size` is right.

> Constructs the string with the first count characters of character
>   string pointed to by s. s can contain null characters. The length of
>   the string is count. The behavior is undefined if s does not point at
>   an array of at least count elements of CharT.

So just use

```
std::string message(static_cast<const char*>(data), size);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can cast `data` to `const char*`, then use the `std::string` two iterator constructor.

```
const char* sdata = static_cast<const char*>(data);
std::string message(sdata, sdata + size);
```

Note that is all you need is a byte buffer, it might be simpler and clearer to use an `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead.

```
const unsigned char* sdata = static_cast<const unsigned char*>(data);
std::vector<unsigned char> message(sdata, sdata + size);
```

Comment: @vladon No problem. Also note the other answer uses a different constructor. The one I use is common among standard library containers, but `std::string` has a larger interface.

Answer (score 1):

As long as size indicates the correct number, casting is fine. You can have `NULL` anywhere `std::string` and you don't even need to NULL terminate your buffer for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

And of course, if you already have a `string` object

```
myString.insert(0, static_cast<const char*>(data), size);
                ^^ -- starting index
```

which calls

```
basic_string& insert( size_type index, const CharT* s, size_type count );
```

[§](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert)

> Inserts the first count characters from the character string pointed to by s at the position index. s can contain null characters.